# Maximum at any point of two lines in R

Tags: r

Suppose you have two lines, L1 and L2, which for each x value (x1 and x2 for example) they have known points at `L1={(x1,L1_y1), (x2,L1_y2)}`, and `L2={(x1,L2_y1), (x2,L2_y2)}`. By joining these points they may or may not have an intersection at some x3 where x1

Now suppose you want to know the maximum at any x value (not restricted to just x1, x2 etc, but anywhere along the axis) of both of these lines. Obviously it is often trivial to calculate for just a few lines, and a few different x value, but in my case I have several tens of thousand x values and a few lines to check it against, so it can't be done manually.

**In R, is there some code which will calculate the maximum at any given point x3?**

An example of this can be seen here with L1={(1,1), (2,4)}, and L2={(1,4),(2,1)}, illustrated by:

[image: Example plot of two lines]

Here the intersection of these lines is at (1.5, 2.5). L2 is the maximum before this, and L1 after. This maximum line is shown in red below.
[image: What I am after]

As you can see, it isn't enough just to take the max at every point and join these up, and so it will need to consider the lines as some form of function, and then take the maximum of this.

Also, as mention before as there are several thousand x values it will need to generalise to larger data.

To test the code further if you wish you can randomly generate y values for some x values, and it will be clear to see from a plot if it works correctly or not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: reproducible example would help this question a lot.

Comment: Is the data from the plots not surely enough?

Comment: Not enough if this is a programming question. If it is not maybe the question doesn't belong on this site...

Comment: Any pair of intersecting lines will be enough. I hardly think I need to provide examples of lines intersecting

Comment: How are you defining your line in R? As a set of two points?

Comment: Yep. So in my example above line 1 is (1,1) to (2,4) and line 2 is (1,4) to (2,1)

Comment: But will this example scale to your actual data (ie, several thousand points)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining points constituting your lines from the example

```
L1 <- list(x = c(1, 2), y = c(1, 4))
L2 <- list(x = c(1, 2), y = c(4, 1))
```

defining a *function* taking a pointwise maximum of two *functions* corresponding to the lines

```
myMax <- function(x)
  pmax(approxfun(L1$x, L1$y)(x), approxfun(L2$x, L2$y)(x))
```

This gives

```
plot(L1$x, L1$y, type = 'l')
lines(L2$x, L2$y, col = 'red')
curve(myMax(x), from = 1, to = 2, col = 'blue', add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Clearly this extends to more complex `L1` and `L2` as `approxfun` is just a piecewise-linear approximation. Also, you may add `L3`, `L4`, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for this! It seems to be working perfectly when I apply it to a subset of my data